# Google Guava Eventbus and Swing Modal Dialogs

Tags: java, swing, events, modal-dialog, guava

I am exploring the use of the Guava EventBus in a Swing application and everything works fine so far, with one exception that is related to modal dialogs.

When my application shows a modal JDialog (let's call it dialog1) and events are posted by this dialog, everything is fine, which means that these events are immediately received by subscribers within and outside the modal dialog.

But if my application shows a different modal JDialog (let's call it dialog2), and if this dialog2 creates the aforementioned dialog1 and shows it modally, the events posted by dialog1 are queued up until dialog1 is closed, so that the subscribers do not receive them immediately.

I do not understand why it works fine in the first case but not in the second.

If it would not work in both cases, I would think that it would be caused by the modality
blocking other stuff outside the modal dialog. But as the first case works fine and so
I am confused.

Any hints would be very appreciated!

Cheers,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying that you open a modal dialog (`dialog1`) in response to an event, and then actions on that dialog post more events to the same `EventBus`? In that case, this is an issue with how `EventBus` handles events posted on the same thread while handling another event: it queues them up until handling of the first event completes, to ensure that events are handled strictly in the order they're posted. The model it's using generally assumes that your event handling code won't tie up the thread indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you must be right. What would be the correct way to solve this? Add a second event bus instance that handles the events within the dialog?

Comment: @user3576825: Yes, that would be one solution provided you can register anything that needs to listen for the events with that `EventBus`. If there are things registered with the first `EventBus` that need to receive some of these events before the dialog is closed, that might not work.

Comment: So as far as I understand, EventBus considers events as dispatched when all methods that subscribed to the event have run. Is that correct? If yes, then I assume it would be wise to start long-running stuff in the event handling methods with EventQueue.invokeLater(). Correct? I also wonder if there is documentation for EventBus apart from the Javadocs and the stuff at https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained. Is there any?

Comment: @user3576825: What I did in the past when I used `EventBus` with Swing was actually to use `AsyncEventBus`, giving it an `Executor` that calls `EventQueue.invokeLater()`. This might be the best solution for you: `AsyncEventBus` doesn't have the queueing issue at all, and this also has the nice property of ensuring that events posted from background threads are handled on the event queue, allowing UI stuff to work correctly. And yeah, that's about it in terms of documentation for `EventBus`.